# Does transfering data to a new iPhone from old iPhone keep all app state?

Tags: data-transfer, migration

Let's say I bought the latest iPhone.
I migrate my data from my old iPhone to the new iPhone.

What does the transfer does to my banking app for example?

Will I still be logged in the new iPhone or it will consider the banking app to a freshly new installed app?

Answer (score 12):

This depends on the app, as apps can mark keychain items and files as being contained to the current device. Those items and files are not transferred.

Especially banking apps make use of this to tie the app instance to a device; after migrating to a new device you often have to re-authenticate. See the support page of your banking app for details.

Comment: +1.  An app that is seen as "security", such as banking, rolling code for 2-factor authentication, etc., is likely to deliberately _not_ store everything to the cloud or allow direct transfer between devices.  Allowing, say, a private key to be exported from an app means one more attack surface to defend.

Comment: I did a migration recently and I can confirm that (at least in the UK) Barclays, HSBC and Wise apps all needed reauthentication/activation, while apps like Uber or Deliveroo just worked. All Apple Pay cards also had to be added again.

Comment: Ditto for the USA - had to re-enter most, but not all, of my credit card/banking data.  I have been told that if you have made an encrypted backup of your iPhone to your computer, and it is to that backup that you go to set up your new iPhone, 99.999% of your data will carry over th the new iPhone. Can any one confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

Apps with logins will usually log you out, so get all the login info before you delete the old phone data. I recently transferred my data from an old iPhone to a new iPhone and found that Apple has a newer method to transfer data that will make it easier and retains the data for most apps.

Before doing this method, I recommend you go to your iPhone **Settings** > click on your **name/profile** at the very top > **iCloud** > make sure everything setting is turned on for backup. Do not worry about buying iCloud storage, they have a new feature that gives you enough iCloud storage so that you can transfer data to your new phone. [Here is a link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212732) to the Apple article explaining exactly how to do this.

For me, all my apps were normal and still had the same exact data where I last left off (even some apps that I thought would reset the score/reset my progress got saved because I turned on all settings in the iCloud section I mentioned).

Also, *do not* reset/delete your old iPhone data until you have 100% confirmed all your data and apps are in your new phone. Trust me, check every app, make sure everything is good before deleting your old phone data because there are multiple ways to still recover that old phone data if it did not transfer properly.